# PHP Download image from url generated by PHP script

Tags: php

i have problem. I need to download image from URL but image URL is not end with JPG, PNG or some others img filetype. This image is generated by PHP script.

Here is a image:
https://www.baza-firm.com.pl/includes/adem.php?usr=Yml1cm8=&dmn=dG9wYXotbWV0YWxlLmNvbS5wbA==&mobEml=0

How i can download this image using PHP script?

Comment: If you check the headers for that URL, you'll see `Content-Type: image/png`. You'll need to interpret the content type header and save with an appropriate extension for whatever type the files are.

Answer (score 0):

if you have `allow_url_fopen=1` in php.ini, you can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$image_binary=file_get_contents($url);
```

, otherwise, if you have php-curl installed, you can use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php)

```
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$image_binary=curl_exec($ch);
```

. if you have neither allow_url_fopen nor curl, you can use the [socket api](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php)

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    die("socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));
}
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, 80);
if ($result === false) {
    die("socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));
}
$out=implode("\r\n",array("GET ".substr($url,strpos($url,"/"))." http/1.0","User-Agent: foobar","","");
socket_send($socket,$out,strlen($out),0);
$last='';
$total='';
while(!!socket_recv($socket,$last,2048,MSG_WAITALL)){
    $total.=$last;
    $last='';
}
socket_close($socket);
$image_binary=substr($total,strpos($total,"\r\n\r\n"));
```